# Is there a way to make Windows 10 "Quick access" links identifiable?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I guess I visit a lot of different folders and many of them have similar sounding, non-distinctive names within UNC paths etc.

For example names like "bin", "Releases", "Windows". Hence, unlike the old favorites feature, the quick access feature in explorer which tries to point out recently accessed folders is completely useless to me because it just fills up with indistinct items which can't be identified. Worse still, if I add an item I don't seem to be able to rename it so I just end up with 5 "Release" folders etc.

It's a really terrible assumption to think that individual folder names will be meaningful to users when it's often the full path that gives significance.

I've worked out that it's possible to turn off the "recent" aspect of quick access but is it possible to get the other benefit of favourites back? I.e. the ability to rename things to distinctive names? I've tried creating symlinks and dragging the symlinks into the quick access vie but unfortunately that just resolves the symlink and adds the underlying folder.

Answer (score 3):

I have a rather silly but hopefully effective solution.  I created a folder in C:\Tools called "Favorite Shortcuts".  Pin that folder to the Quick Access.  Then I link all the folders I want to keep in that folder as shortcuts.  I can rename these shortcuts however I want.

But the downside is this: to access my "favorite folders", I need to first click on the Quick Access link to the shortcut folder, and then click on the short cuts.  It is now a 2 step process, instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue myself - here are some workarounds:

**To rename a Quick Access item:**

1. Select "Quick Access" on the left in Explorer
2. The item on the right in Explorer > Properties (somehow, it doesn't let you change the name on the left)

**To not resolve the UNC name when placing a symbolic link in Quick Access.
From the Command Prompt:**

1. Delete the symbolic link
2. Make a regular directory with the identical name of the symbolic link
3. Pin that directory to Quick Start
4. Remove that directory and replace it with the identically-named symbolic link

Comment: The problem with renaming the quick item as you suggest is that it actually renames the underlying folder.  So I have to go and rename the "Releases" folder for everyone on the SMB share, not just give it a meaningful name to me..  The second tip is actually what something like what I'm doing now.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "This PC" and right-click to "Add a network location".

These are kind of an upgrade to the Mapped Drive concept in that they don't require you to assign some arbitrary drive letter.  Network Locations can be aliased to whatever name you want and they appear as shortcuts in your "This PC" pane underneath the Quick Access pane.

This is not quite as good as having all your network shortcuts grouped with your favorite local locations, but with some creative naming you can at least get all your network locations to group together logically.

You can pin these to your Quick Access pane, but it doesn't do you any good because Quick Access still shows a link to the actual entity, so if your Network Location is named "Something Sensible" and the actual folder you reference is `\\acobuendkfoucb\1xxfdoeurinb`, you're going to get a "1xxfdoeurinb" item in Quick Access.

And don't rename that Quick Access item.